# Why can I no longer find gnome-mahjongg with apt?

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+

I have installed the new release of Stretch for the Pi 3 B+. Apt goes to the Inrelease on the mirror and it does not seem to have the games?  I like the Gnome-mahjongg package, but apt-cache search finds no mahjongg or card games. Only game in the pixel desktop is Minecraft.

/etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

Why am I no longer able to find gnome-mahjongg or other similar games packages with apt?

Comment: @Joseph Have you tried running apt-get update to refresh the package lists first? Retry searching/installing after running that, if you haven't already.

Comment: Yes I did.  I have two units with this version of stretch and results are the same.

Comment: Thank you For your comments.  The repository maintainers for the new pi must have done something, both units find the games now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved long time ago. The OP wrote in a comment:

> Thank you For your comments. The repository maintainers for the new pi must have done something, both units find the games now. – Joseph T Tannenbaum Mar 29 '18 at 1:14

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your set up.

Are you sure you have updated the package lists?

```
pi3b:~ $ apt-cache search mahjong
gnome-mahjongg - classic Eastern tile game for GNOME
kajongg - classical Mah Jongg game
kdegames-mahjongg-data - tilesets and backgrounds for Mahjongg games
kdegames-mahjongg-data-kf5 - tilesets and backgrounds for Mahjongg games
kmahjongg - mahjongg solitaire game
kshisen - Shisen-Sho solitaire game
libkf5kmahjongglib-dev - development files for the KDE kmahjongg library
libkf5kmahjongglib5 - shared library for kmahjongg and kshisen
libkmahjongglib-dev - development files for the KDE kmahjongg library
libkmahjongglib4 - shared library for kmahjongg and kshisen
mednafen - multi-platform emulator, including NES, GB/A, Lynx, PC Engine
pysolfc - collection of more than 1000 solitaire card games
xmahjongg - tile-based solitaire game

pi3b:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
pi3b:~ $
```

Comment: I started with the new Rasbian-stretch with desktop image that was released with the pi3 b+

Comment: PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"